# How to handle a create form with one to many relation in Yii?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

I work with Yii 1.1. I wish to make a create form, which creates a module. A *module* belongs to one *user*. A *user* has many *modules*.

```
tbl_user
----------
id
firstName
lastName
email
password
role
```

and

```
tbl_user_module
----------
id
name
academicYear
....
userId [FOREIGN KEY]
```

The relations in models are set up as follow:

**Module.php**

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'userId'),
    );
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'module' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Module', 'userId'),
    );
}
```

A user uses a from to create a module, which belongs to him (logged in user). In the controller, I need to assign the userId foreign key as the logged in user.

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $module = new Module();

        // collect user input data
        if(isset($_POST['Module']))
        {       
            $module->attributes=$_POST['Module'];
            $module->userId = Yii::app()->user->id; //assigned userID as logged in user

            if($module->validate())
            {               
                if($module->save())
                {
                    $this->redirect(array('home/index'));
                }
            }
        }

        //render
        $this->render('create',array('model'=>$module));
    }
```

The form is not saved and throws an error:

```
Property "Module.$userId" is not defined.
```

Obviously, I am not doing it right. **How do I properly save a one-to-many relations in a form?**

Comment: Also, when you do $module->save() it triggers validate() automatically, so you are validating input twice here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I had a typo in Module.php!